# How can I tell the source location of a package installed with pip?

Tags: python, svn, pip

I have python package stored in a SVN repo.  When i check it out and install it locally like this

```
cd path/to/package/checkout
pip install -e .
```

After doing a pip freeze

```
pip freeze |grep PKG
```

I get

```
 -e svn+https://svnhost/PKG/branches/release-0.18.x@1046#egg=PKG-0.18.0_pre-py2.7-release-0.18.x-r1046
```

It look like it has been installed directly from SVN instead of my local copy.
Is there a way to tell what the actual origin of the package is?

Answer (score 1):

`pip freeze` gave you exactly that. The source location of the SVN repo and the commit revision (1046).

You can check the location of the files once imported, to examine where they resides. That will probably point you to `path/to/package/checkout`:

```
$ python
>> import packagename
>> packagename.__file__
'path/to/package/checkout/__init__.py'
```

Comment: So i have to import each package to see where it is installed from?

Comment: `pip3 show packagename [other package names]` is an alternative to this import.